# Why MySQL is ignoring my indexes in a query?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, mysql-5.5, query-performance

I have the following query in a production database server(master):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Enlace_llamadas 
where id_empresa IN (1,5,33,36,40,44,48,53,55,111,115,125,127,151,167,175,181,185,187,189,195,199,201,203,207,209,221,223,231,233,239,241,243,244,247,249,251,253,257,259,261,276,277,281,283,287,291,293,301,305,307,313,315,319,323,339,341,343,345,359,367,371,379,381,383,385,387,391,393,395,397,421,423,425,429,431,433,437,439,441,445,447,451,454,463,469,477,479,481,489,491,495,497,501,507,510,514,520,522) 
  AND date(fecha_inicio)=date(NOW()) 
  and Enlace_llamadas.fecha_fin='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fecha_inicio, NOW()) >= '5';
```

Running EXPLAIN inside this server, this was the result:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                                                          | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Enlace_llamadas | ALL  | id_empresa_id_agente,idx_empresa_campana,id_empresa_cliente,id_empresa | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 41330453 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+------------------------
```

this query takes long time , almost 40 seconds of execution and the machine resources use a lot of CPU above 0f 500%. Executing `SHOW INDEX FROM nombre_tabla`, this was the result table.

```
| Enlace_llamadas |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id                | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_campana               |            1 | id_campana        | A         |       19700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_cliente               |            1 | id_cliente        | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_numero_cliente        |            1 | id_numero_cliente | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_id_agente     |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_id_agente     |            2 | id_agente         | A         |       19468 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | idx_empresa_campana      |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | idx_empresa_campana      |            2 | id_campana        | A         |       19569 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_cliente       |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_cliente       |            2 | id_cliente        | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas |            1 | fecha_inicio      | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas |            2 | fecha_fin         | A         |    41330863 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_agente                |            1 | id_agente         | A         |        8516 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa               |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This same query in another server(slave) takes 0.21 seconds. This is the execution plan in the slave server.

```
 id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys                                                                                   | key                      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | Enlace_llamadas | ref  | id_empresa,i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas,id_empresa_id_agente,id_empresa_cliente,idx_empresa_campana | i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas | 8       | const |  276 | Using index condition; Using where
```

The indexes on this table from this server

```
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Enlace_llamadas |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id                | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_campana               |            1 | id_campana        | A         |       78826 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_cliente               |            1 | id_cliente        | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_numero_cliente        |            1 | id_numero_cliente | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_agente                |            1 | id_agente         | A         |        9389 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa               |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas |            1 | fecha_fin         | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas |            2 | fecha_inicio      | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_id_agente     |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_id_agente     |            2 | id_agente         | A         |       42663 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_cliente       |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | id_empresa_cliente       |            2 | id_cliente        | A         |    46034401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | idx_empresa_campana      |            1 | id_empresa        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Enlace_llamadas |          1 | idx_empresa_campana      |            2 | id_campana        | A         |       22271 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the reason from this?

Comment: Tip on improving fecha_inicio usage in your index.  `fecha_inicio BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`. Expressions on a column hamper index usage. You should see an increase in key_length in the explain, after correcting as per answer.

Comment: @danblack He has 2 different conditions which compares fecha_inicio  and NOW(). They may be combined into one complex condition which uses 2 CASEs on NOW().

Answer (score 4):

Once you format your output correctly, you can see that the definition of `i_Enlace_llamadas_fechas` differs between the two servers -- the column order is reversed in the second server, which makes it suitable for the query there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide columns in functions, if you need them to be indexed.

```
AND date(fecha_inicio)=date(NOW())
```

If `fecha_inicio` is of type `DATE`, simply do

```
AND fecha_inicio = CURDATE()
```

If it is `DATETIME`, then do

```
AND fecha_inicio >= CURDATE()
AND fecha_inicio  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

What is this doing?

```
and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fecha_inicio, NOW()) >= '5';
```

If it is checking to see if it is in the last 5 minutes, simply do

```
AND fecha_inicio > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

and get rid of the date test (unless there is something special about spanning midnight).

Then have this composite index:

```
INDEX(fecha_fin, id_empresa, fecha_inicio)  -- in this  order
```

If you need to discuss further, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
MySQL version
Size of tables
```